# When will send() return EWOULDBLOCK?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, send, nonblocking

I'm working with an application now that uses mostly blocking sockets with select() timeouts, but with the Write function, I'm using nonblocking sockets with send(). I just need to know, under what (and all) circumstances will send() return EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, or else maybe you don't understand the documentation.  `send()` will return either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if the socket is in non-blocking mode and the call would block for any reason.  The specifications do not go into any more detail, and the details would in any event be implementation-specific.  For some implementations, it means that there is not enough free space in the send buffer to accommodate the whole message, but buffering details are, again, implementation-specific.

Comment: @JohnBollinger For all implementations. Send buffers are mentioned in the documentation. They are not an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Linux man page for `send()` says:

> When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
>   send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
>   nonblocking I/O mode. In nonblocking mode it would fail with the error
>   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in this case. The select(2) call may be used to
>   determine when it is possible to send more data.

and

> Return values **EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK**: The socket is marked nonblocking and the
>   requested operation would block. POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to
>   be returned for this case, and does not require these constants to
>   have the same value, so a portable application should check for both
>   possibilities.